# How to import Android sample into Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to import sample code from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) into Eclipse. It doesn't include ANY build instructions.

I have tried using the "import existing android code into workspace" and "new android project from existing source" but neither option recognizes the folder which I downloaded because it only contains `src` and `res` folders. I have tried overwriting a new project's `src` and `res` folders with the ones provided in the sample and updating the manifest with the new MainActivity but this produces a "R cannot be resolved to a variable error" which can't be corrected through cleaning and rebuilding. I have also tried dropping the folder into `sdk/samples` and copying and updating the manifest from another sample but this again produces the "R cannot be resolved" error.

Comment: Which sample project are you looking to import? Can you post the link?

Comment: Hi, I have included the sample link in the description but here it is: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new android project. Then:

> File-> Import -> File System.

From Directory: your folder containing src, res (check the box)

Into Folder: your created project

Or you can just manually copy and paste classes and things you need into your project using explorer, and then refresh the project to see them.

Comment: That did the trick although I suspect that the error I was getting due to my own mistake. The sample package was _com.example.android.customviews_ and I was mistakenly using _com.example.android.customview_ in my manifest. Still the trick with the filesystem import will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 4):

File > New Project > Android > Android Sample Project > Chose the Platform > Choose the project from the list. It should be ready to go!

Comment: You might need to select the project target once again and try cleaning the project. I even tried now on my eclipse and i was able to create a project from the sample